# Is my laburnam tree dead?

Tags: tree-care

No leaves have emerged yet and I think they should have by now. Also I can see no leaf buds. It is about twenty years old and never had any problems before.  There is a lot of sway when I push the trunk which I have not noticed before. Advice, suggestions?

Comment: Check the trunk from top to bottom -you're looking for soft areas, splits, cracks, anything seeping, or soggy areas, especially at the base - there has to be a reason why there's a lot of sway, so also check that the soil around the base of the tree is still firm and hasn't been eroded. Then add the info to your question please, as well as telling us where you are in the world.

Comment: A picture really helps